# sql COALESCE result (12300.4567) to 12,300

Tags: mysql

How to select COALESCE result to format( , 0)

my query is

```
SELECT (COALESCE((SELECT SUM(`invoices`.`paid_amount`) FROM `invoices`
          WHERE DATE(`invoices`.`date`)=CURDATE()),0) + 
         COALESCE((SELECT SUM(`other_incomes`.`other_income_amount`) FROM `other_incomes`
          WHERE DATE(`other_incomes`.`date`)=CURDATE()),0)) 
      AS total
FROM 
   ....
```

Comment: COALESCE does not format the value. It returns first non-NULL value from its operands list (in your case - it returns zero if the subquery returns NULL or empty dataset). You need additional ROUND() or CEIL()/FLOOR().

Comment: I'm looking at your query and I think it can be written much shorter and more understandable like in this example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b0f826563043d41b2246802826e29f0a

Answer (score 0):

Primarily, COALESCE doesn't change the formatting.  It only returns the first non-null value passed to it.

Also, instead of trying to join or do two different queries and adding, and handling all the sums and coalesces separately (not to mention the rounding), I would probably UNION all the relevant results together, then handle the coalesce/sum/round all at the end.

Try this:

```
SELECT round(sum(coalesce(amt, 0)), 0) as total
FROM (
  SELECT paid_amount as amt
  FROM invoices i
  WHERE date(i.date) = CURDATE()
  
  union all
  
  SELECT other_income_amount
  FROM other_incomes o
  WHERE date(o.date) = CURDATE()
) z
```

Here I COALESCE first, to make nulls be 0 instead.  I wrap that in a SUM to add up the values, and finally a ROUND to get the format.  It was unclear from the question is you wanted to ROUND or FLOOR.  If you are looking to get it with that comma, use FORMAT.  Here's the mySQL documentation for that.  You didn't specify your SQL flavor.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format

Additionally, you should include your sql platform and version, the create statements for your tables, along with some insert statements that will provide sample data, along with the results you are looking for.  It will help people answer your question.  If you can include a fiddle, like https://dbfiddle.uk/, that would be nice.